# Is it more memory-efficient to assign a variable to an expression?

Tags: c#, .net

What's more efficient?

```
decimal value1, value2, formula
```

This:

```
for(int i = 0; i>1000000000000; i++);
 {
        value1 = getVal1fromSomeWhere();
        value2 = getVal2fromSomeWhere(); 
        SendResultToA( value1*value2 + value1/value2);
        SendResultToB( value1*value2 + value1/value2);
 }
```

Or this:

```
for(int i = 0; i>1000000000000; i++)
{
        value1 = getVal1fromSomeWhere();
        value2 = getVal2fromSomeWhere();
        formula = value1*value2 + value1/value2;
        SendResultToA(formula);
        SendResultToA(formula);
}
```

Intuitively I would go for the latter...

I guess there's a tradeoff between having an extra-assignment at each iteration (`decimal`, `formula`) and performing the computation on and on with no extra-variable...

**EDIT :** 
Uhhh. God... Do I Have to go through this each time I ask a question ?
If I ask it, it is because **YES** it **DOES MATTER** to me, fellows.
Everybody does not live in a gentle non-memory-critical world, WAKE-UP !
this was just an overly simple example. I am doing **MILLIONS** of scientific computation and clouding multithreaded stuff, do not take me for a noob :-)
So **YES**,  **DEFINITELY** every nanosecond counts.

**PS :** I almost regret C++ and pointers. Automatic Memory Management and GC's definitely made developers ignorant and lazy :-P

Comment: If you write performance critical code you should really learn how to profile and inspect the generated machine-code. That's the only way to be really sure what's happening.

Comment: Yes you're 100% right. Didn't need to get so deep with my App until now. Gonna dig that further.

Comment: And as a sidenote: I think you can get Mono to use SSE vector instructions which can give you a real boost in calculations which profit from them.

Comment: As your loop is written btw, it will execute very very quickly, since the condition is flipped :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all profile first, and only do such micro optimizations if it's necessary. Else optimize for readability. And in your case I think the second one is easier to read.

And your statement that the second code has an additional assignment isn't true anyways. The result of your formula needs to be stored into a register in both codes.
The concept of the extra variable isn't valid once the code is compiled. For example in your case the compiler can store `formula` in the register where `value1` or `value2` was stored before, since their lifetimes don't overlap.

I wouldn't be surprised if the first one gets optimized to the second one. I think this optimization is called "Common subexpression folding". But of course it's only possible if the expression is free of side-effects.

And inspecting the IL isn't always enough to see what gets optimized. The jitter optimizes too. I had some code that was quite ugly and slow looking in IL, but very short in the finally generated x86 code. And when inspecting the machine code you need to make sure it's actually optimized. For example if you run in VS even the release code isn't fully optimized.

So my guess is that they are equally fast if the compiler can optimize them, and else the second one is faster since it doesn't need to evaluate your formula twice.

Comment: Oki Doki Dude. That was very insightful, and relevant to what I was looking for as an answer. As I am deploying that code on x86 monocore machine as well as on powerful x64 24 Core servers (I manage both cases in code)Do you have any general extra-advice on How to monitor real efficiency /explore machine code ? (Woooh, I did not do this since Assembly Course in College... :-) )

Comment: To get at the machine code I usually place a `Debugger.Break()` before my code, then compile as Release(optimizations on), and run the myproject.exe. You'll then be asked to attach a debugger once your `Debugger.Break()` is hit. Depending on what exactly I want to do I choose either VS or OllyDbg.

Comment: As for profiling there are a number of profilers for .net, but I don't have much experience with them. Or you can do it manually using `StopWatch` or `QueryPerformanceCounter`. Their values can be nonsensical though on some (buggy) multicode systems. For example on my comp `QueryPerformanceCounter` can jump backwards in time if the thread switches the core.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're doing this tens of thousands of times a second, it doesn't matter at all. Optimize towards readability and maintainability!

**Edit:** Haters gonna hate, okay fine, here you go. My code:

```
static void MethodA()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var value1 = getVal1fromSomeWhere();
        var value2 = getVal2fromSomeWhere();
        SendResultToA(value1 * value2 + value1 / value2);
        SendResultToB(value1 * value2 + value1 / value2);
    }
}

static void MethodB()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var value1 = getVal1fromSomeWhere();
        var value2 = getVal2fromSomeWhere();
        var formula = value1 * value2 + value1 / value2;
        SendResultToA(formula);
        SendResultToB(formula);
    }
}
```

And the actual x86 assembly generated by both of them:

MethodA: http://pastie.org/1532794

MethodB: http://pastie.org/1532792

These are very long because it inlined getVal[1/2]fromSomewhere and SendResultTo[A/B], which I wired up to Random and Console.WriteLine. We can see that indeed, the CLR nor the Jitter is not smart enough to not duplicate the previous calculation, so we spend an additional 318 bytes of x86 bytecode doing the extra math.

However, keep this in mind - any gains you make by these kinds of optimizations are immediately made irrelevant by even a single extra page fault or disk read/write. These days, CPUs are rarely the bottleneck in most applications - I/O and memory are. Optimize toward spatial locality (i.e using contiguous arrays so you hit less page faults), and reducing disk I/O and hard page faults (i.e. loading code you don't need requires the OS to fault it in).

Comment: The OP was not asking which is better practice, but which is more efficient.  Yes, premature optimization, blah blah blah.  **We get it.** Does that mean we cannot have a discussion about actual efficiency?

Comment: Yeah this was just an example, the operations I do are a bit more complex and recurrent, over many threads, so It does matter to me.

Comment: +1 for hard data.  I'm not a hater, just tired of these pat responses, which are not answers.

Comment: @harpo: No actually, you cannot have a meaningful *discussion* about *actual efficiency*. The way to get actual efficiency is to *measure performance under carefully controlled conditions*, as Paul has. Discussion from our armchairs without data is pointless; it's theorizing in advance of facts, rather than from a position of knowledge. Efficiency is not achieved by random people on the internet guessing which is better.

Comment: @Eric, as a maniacal word parser myself, I appreciate the fine distinction you make.  I defer to both your and Paul's greater knowledge in this area.  Yet, see his first answer for the context of my comment.

Comment: And yes, I understand that "knowledge" is still no substitute for facts.  But you have to know when and how to conduct the proper tests.

Answer (score 3):

To the extent that it might matter, I think you're right.  And both are equally readable (arguably).

Remember, the number of loop iterations has nothing to do with the local memory requirements.  You're only talking about a few extra bytes, (and the value is going to be put on the stack for passage to the function, anyway); whereas the cycles you save* by caching the result of the calculation *does* go down significantly with the number of iterations.

*** That is, provided that the compiler doesn't do this for you.  It would be instructive to look at the IL generated in each case.

Comment: I don't think both are equally readable - the second is clearer. Also less error prone: in the first case there is always the chance that someone slightly modifies only *one* of the expressions.

Comment: @Peter, I agree... but for such a simple case I do think it is arguable.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to disassemble the bytecode and/or benchmark to be sure but I'd argue that this would probably be the same since it's trivial for the compiler to see that `formula` (in the loop scope) does not change and can quite easily be 'inlined' (substituted) directly.

**EDIT**: As user CodeInChaos correctly comments disassembling  the bytecode might not be enough since it's possible the optimisation is only introduced after jitting.

Comment: Disassembling the byte code isn't always enough(might be in this case). You usually need to disassemble the jitted code.